# What does actually 'working on the go' express in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, writing-style

> This little guy is perfect for anyone **working on the go**; it's comfortable, lightweight, and fits perfectly in a purse or bag.

I can't understand the main meaning of the sentence using 'working on the go'.
Is it about working at the time of traveling or moving or anything else?

Are there any way to rewrite above sentence in simplest form?

Answer (score 2):

"working on the go" means working while traveling.

The sentence you quote is part of an ad for a computer mouse, which is what "this little guy" is.

So the sentence could be rephrased: This small computer mouse is perfect for anyone working on a computer while traveling.

You can look up "on the go" in dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

"working on the go" is similar to "on the fly". The person uses this phrase to express the easiness of the tool(probably) which requires no extra care to handle it.

Comment: It's nothing to do with "easiness of the tool." From the original quote, "it's comfortable, lightweight and fits perfectly in a purse or bag."